# Grails Spring Social Plugin Build Error

Tags: spring, grails, spring-social

I get the following error when trying to compile my Grails App using Spring Social plugin:

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/social/ApiBinding
```

This is what I have added to my `BuildConfig.groovy` plugins section:

```
compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
compile ":spring-security-facebook:0.14.5"
compile ":spring-social-core:0.1.31"
compile ":spring-social-facebook:0.1.32"
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes I solved it by dropping Grails!!! I'm back to pure Spring! :-) Too much headache for me. These languages sitting on top of each other are supposed to make your life easier but in most of the cases they just make it harder!

Comment: Thanks :). I think I've just partially solved it by switching to the ":spring-security-facebook:0.15" plugin, which itself downloads newer versions of the Spring Social plugins directly from the Spring repo. As far as I can tell the main problem was that the Spring Social Core/Facebook/Twitter plugins for Grails are years out of date and incompatible with recent versions of Spring Security and/or Grails.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and think I've just solved it by switching to the ["spring-security-facebook"](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) and ["spring-security-twitter"](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-twitter) Grails plugins, which themselves just source current versions of the [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) plugins directly from SpringSource repos.

I'm using the following with Grails 2.3.0 without errors:

Custom repositories:

```
mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/"
mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/"
mavenRepo "http://maven.springframework.org/release/"
```

Plugins:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
compile ":spring-security-facebook:0.15"
compile ":spring-security-twitter:0.5.4"
```

As far as I can tell the problem was simply that the [Spring Social Core/Facebook/Twitter plugins for Grails](http://grails.org/search?q=spring%20social) are years out of date (last updated in 2011) and incompatible with recent versions of Spring Security and/or Grails.